# initramfs-tools doesn't have a root folder

Tags: lvm, initramfs

I'm trying to setup remote ssh to an encrypted lvm server following the instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot). But they assume there are files in /etc/initramfs-tools/root but my brand new 16.04 install has no root folder. Have these been moved?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

On a remote server you should create `sudo mkdir /etc/initramfs-tools/root && sudo mkdir /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh` 
Then `sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and insert you pub keys from your local host `nano ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.